# Can persistence be checked to exist?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase enables a user login to persist. However, the user is not available on page load. The app must listen to `onAuthStateChanged` to know when the user is made available. The wait is short, but not insignificant.

Is there any way to detect whether a user can be persisted *before* the user is made available? This would be helpful, to tailor the user experience suitably.

Looking in `localStorage`, the data seems available, and so one would imagine that a simple method could return `true` or `false` whether any persistence data is available in `localStorage`. However, I could not find such a method in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple utility function to detect and return what appears to be the relevant item in `localStorage`. Obviously, though, an official method would be preferable.

```
// Title: Get Persistent User
// Description: Returns the persistent user data recorded by Firebase.
export function getPersistentUser()
{
    const expression = /^firebase:authUser/;
    const keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    for (let index = 0; index < keys.length; index++)
    {
        const key = keys[index];
        if (expression.test(key))
        {
            const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
            return item;
        };
    };
    return null;
};
```